# iOS/Objective-C Google Cloud Storage upload file

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to add google cloud storage to iOS app. I already played with it on android and it work fine. I did not test it well but it looks good. 
I search a lot however, I did not find anything close to what i did on android.

I found example but it is really confused for beginner iOS developer
https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/master/Examples/StorageSample/StorageSampleWindowController.m

On Android i did like this:

```
Credentials credentials;

InputStream iStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential);
credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(iStream);

Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(CommonSharedData.GCP_PROJECT).build().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(CommonSharedData.GCP_BUCKET, CommonSharedData.MEDIA_DIR + "/" + fileName.getName());

BlobInfo blobInfo = null;
blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType(CommonSharedData.GCP_IMAGE_JPG).build();

byte[] stream = bytesArray(fileName);

Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, stream);
Acl acl = storage.createAcl(blobId, Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER));
```

credential file structure:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "blablalbla",
  "private_key_id": "blablalbla",
  "private_key": "blablalbla",
  "client_email": "blablalbla",
  "client_id": "blablalbla",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "blablalbla"
}
```

But I can not find something simple like that for iOS on objective C.

I just need simple working example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I can use direct APIs to use google cloud on iOS.
I have to use firebase as layer. But they have amazing code.